# Why the array is not sorted correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

the problem is

> arange the columns of the array X (n, m) in ascending order.

I wrote such code in c ++ myself, but in the end it does not sort all the columns correctly. Please help if anyone knows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, m;
    cout << "array size: n = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "array size: m = ";
    cin >> m;
    int array[n][m];
    int arrayS[n];
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < m; a++) {
            cin >> array[z][a];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arrayS[i] = array[i][0];
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            cout << array[y][i] << "    ";

        }
        cout << endl; //endline
    }
    cout << "************************************\n";
    cout << "massivin sutunlari\n";
    int enk = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (arrayS[j] > arrayS[j + 1])
            {
                enk = arrayS[j];
                arrayS[j] = arrayS[j + 1];
                arrayS[j + 1] = enk;
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arrayS[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 int n,m;
 cout<<"array size: n = ";
 cin>>n; 
 cout<<"array size: m = ";
 cin>>m; 
 int array[n][m]; 
 int arrayS[n];   
 for(int z=0; z<n; z++) {
  for(int a=0; a<m; a++) { 
   cin>>array[z][a];
  }
 }
 for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {  
  arrayS[i] = array[i][0];
 }
 for (int y=0; y<n; y++) {
  for (int i = 0; i<m; i++) { 
   cout<<array[y][i]<<"    ";

  }
  cout<<endl; //endline
 }
 cout<<"************************************\n";

Comment: cout<<"massivin sutunlari\n";
 int enk = 0;
 
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++) 
  for(int j=0;j<9;j++) 
  { 
  if(arrayS[j]>arrayS[j+1]) 
  { 
  enk=arrayS[j]; 
  arrayS[j]=arrayS[j+1]; 
  arrayS[j+1]=enk; 
  } 
}  
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  cout<<arrayS[i]<<"  ";
 }
}

Comment: please do not post pictures of code or code in comments. This is not useful for us to help you... Instead, just copy and paste the code into your question, select it and click on the "code" button `{}` above the question. Also, before you do that, tell your code editor to format your code, so that it is properly indented. That makes it easier for us and you to read it.

Comment: See the `console.log()` example on how to easily format your text code blocks.

Comment: Farhad, thanks for adding the code. However, you still didn't properly indent it, so it's hard to read. Now, what have you tried to debug this? We can't guess what the program does, and you need to have an idea.

Comment: Some heartfelt advice:  Naming your variables `z` `y` `a` `i` `j` `n` `m` is only appropriate if you _never_ expect anyone else to look at your code.  If someone else needs to look at such code, they may suggest that you are making your code unnecessarily difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to make your code compilable. You are using so called VLA (variable length arrays), like in `int array[n][m];`. Rhese VLAs are not part of the C++ language and will not compile. I replaced them with a `std::vector` which will work in the same way. Then I corrected the code identations (I edited also your question) and then it is possible to compile.

It will then lool like the below (but of course still not working)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n, m;
    std::cout << "array size: n = ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "array size: m = ";
    std::cin >> m;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(n, std::vector<int>(m, 0));
    std::vector<int> arrayS(n);

    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < m; a++) {
            std::cin >> array[z][a];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arrayS[i] = array[i][0];
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            std::cout << array[y][i] << "    ";

        }
        std::cout << std::endl; //endline
    }
    std::cout << "************************************\n";
    std::cout << "massivin sutunlari\n";
    int enk = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (arrayS[j] > arrayS[j + 1])
            {
                enk = arrayS[j];
                arrayS[j] = arrayS[j + 1];
                arrayS[j + 1] = enk;
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arrayS[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

Some basic hints. Please use "speaking" variable names and write many many comments, best, one than more comment per line of code. Then you would already see the problems by yourself.

You have some hard bugs in your code that will most likely crash you program. Where you thy to sort, you use the magic number 9 (for whatever reasons) and so go out of bounds of the define arrays.

Additionally, your implementation of bubble sort is wrong. You may check many many examples in the net.

Then, you do only sort one column. You need to implement a bubble sort for each column of your matrix.

As a next step I will use better variable names and write comments. The code will still not work. But see and understand the difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // Here we will define the dimensions for our matrix
    int numberOfRows{}, numberOfColumns{};

    // Inform user what to do. Enter number of rows of the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the number of rows: ";

    // Read the number of rows from the user via std::cin
    std::cin >> numberOfRows;

    // Inform user what to do. Enter number of columns of the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the number of columns: ";

    // Read the number of rows from the user via std::cin
    std::cin >> numberOfColumns;

    // Define the array for the complete 2d matrix
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns, 0));

    // We can store one column here
    std::vector<int> arrayS(numberOfRows);

    // Inform user what to do. Enter all data for the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter all data for the matrix";

    // Now read all data, for all rows and columns from the user, via std::cin
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            std::cin >> array[row][col];
        }
    }
    // Copy the first column in a separate array
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        arrayS[i] = array[i][0];
    }

    // Show current data in our matrix
    std::cout << "\n\nThe matrix:\n\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            std::cout << array[row][col] << "    ";

        }
        std::cout << '\n'; //endline
    }

    // SHow some status message
    std::cout << "\n\n\n************************************\n";
    std::cout << "Sorted first column\n";

    // This is a temporary variable needed to swap 2 values
    int tempValue = 0;

    // Try to do bubble sort
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (arrayS[j] > arrayS[j + 1])
            {
                tempValue = arrayS[j];
                arrayS[j] = arrayS[j + 1];
                arrayS[j + 1] = tempValue;
            }
        }

    // Show the result of the sorting
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arrayS[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

Next, we fix the sorting for one column.

Only minor changes needed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // Here we will define the dimensions for our matrix
    int numberOfRows{}, numberOfColumns{};

    // Inform user what to do. Enter number of rows of the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the number of rows: ";

    // Read the number of rows from the user via std::cin
    std::cin >> numberOfRows;

    // Inform user what to do. Enter number of columns of the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the number of columns: ";

    // Read the number of rows from the user via std::cin
    std::cin >> numberOfColumns;

    // Define the array for the complete 2d matrix
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns, 0));

    // We can store one column here
    std::vector<int> arrayS(numberOfRows);

    // Inform user what to do. Enter all data for the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter all data for the matrix\n";

    // Now read all data, for all rows and columns from the user, via std::cin
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            std::cin >> array[row][col];
        }
    }
    // Copy the first column in a separate array
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        arrayS[i] = array[i][0];
    }

    // Show current data in our matrix
    std::cout << "\n\nThe matrix:\n\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            std::cout << array[row][col] << "    ";

        }
        std::cout << '\n'; //endline
    }

    // SHow some status message
    std::cout << "\n\n\n************************************\n";
    std::cout << "Sorted first column\n";

    // This is a temporary variable needed to swap 2 values
    int tempValue = 0;

    // Try to do bubble sort
    // Go over all entries-1 in the column array.
    // And compare the current value with the next value
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfRows - 1; j++)
        {
            // If this value is bigger than the following value, then swap them
            if (arrayS[j] > arrayS[j + 1])
            {
                // Swap
                tempValue = arrayS[j];
                arrayS[j] = arrayS[j + 1];
                arrayS[j + 1] = tempValue;
            }
        }

    // Show the result of the sorting
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arrayS[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

This works already. But, my gues is that all columns shall be sorted.

Then, finally, it would look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // Here we will define the dimensions for our matrix
    int numberOfRows{}, numberOfColumns{};

    // Inform user what to do. Enter number of rows of the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the number of rows: ";

    // Read the number of rows from the user via std::cin
    std::cin >> numberOfRows;

    // Inform user what to do. Enter number of columns of the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the number of columns: ";

    // Read the number of rows from the user via std::cin
    std::cin >> numberOfColumns;

    // Define the array for the complete 2d matrix
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns, 0));

    // Inform user what to do. Enter all data for the matrix
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter all data for the matrix\n";

    // Now read all data, for all rows and columns from the user, via std::cin
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            std::cin >> array[row][col];
        }
    }

    // Show current data in our matrix
    std::cout << "\n\nThe matrix:\n\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            std::cout << array[row][col] << "    ";

        }
        std::cout << '\n'; //endline
    }

    // SHow some status message
    std::cout << "\n\n\n************************************\n";
    std::cout << "Matrix with sorted column\n";

    // This is a temporary variable needed to swap 2 values
    int tempValue = 0;

    // Try to do bubble sort
    // Go over all entries-1 in the column array.
    // And compare the current value with the next value
    // Do for all columns
    for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col)
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows-1; ++i)
            for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows - 1; ++row)
            {
                // If this value is bigger than the following value, then swap them
                if (array[row][col] > array[row + 1][col])
                {
                    // Swap
                    tempValue = array[row][col];
                    array[row][col] = array[row + 1][col];
                    array[row + 1][col] = tempValue;
                }
            }

    // Show the result of the sorting
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            std::cout << array[row][col] << "    ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n'; //endline
    }
}
```